# In how many ways can we distribute the black balls

Tags: combinatorics

We have 10 similar black balls. How many ways are there to distribute them into 6 boxes, each box is large enough for all balls.

My idea is $$\binom{10+6-1}{6-1}=\binom{15}{5}=3003$$ is that correct?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.  However, you should explain your reasoning.

Comment: Are the boxes distinguishable? e.g. do you consider the distribution $\{10,0,0,0,0,0\}$ to be different from $\{0,10,0,0,0,0\}$?

Comment: We have only the information that we have 6 boxes, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6 and each one is large enough so that every ball can be fillied in one @DreiCleaner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is correct. I like to view it as arranging $15$ objects in a row, the objects being the $10$ balls and $5$ partitions. This is the so-called "Stars and Bars" method of counting.

One example would be $\bullet|\bullet\bullet|\bullet|\bullet\bullet\bullet||\bullet\bullet\bullet$.

This arrangement has $1$ ball in box $b_1$, $2$ balls in box $b_2$, and so on. Notice that there are $0$ balls in box $b_5$, as indicated by the two adjacent partitions.

There are $\binom{15}{5}$ ways to arrange the balls and partitions, as you said in the question.

Comment: Thank you very much!!  :-)